# Spring-Boot: share an object between components

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a custom object which I like to share between different Spring-Boot components (e.g. WebHandler, Authenticator, Filter).

Maybe the easiest way is a static object in the main-class but thats not very elegant.

Whats the most common way to do it?

Comment: Make a bean out of it and inject it? can you expand your question? Dependency Injection is at the core of Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of spring as a container is to manage your objects.

Now statics do not have a well defined lifecycle ( when exactly this object gets created, who disposes it when the application gets closed, etc)

Speing answers all these questions by using thecdependency injection techniques. If you're already using spring then you should define this 'shared object' as a spring bean (by default it will have scope singleton just like static object that you've proposed but managed by spring container which is better - it will manage the lifecycle of the object by itself)

Then given the classes that must be dependent of the object are beans by themselves you can inject that bean:

```
class MySharedObject {}

class MyWebHandler implementsWebHandler {
  private final MySharedObject mySharedObject;

public MyWebHandler(MySharedObject mySharedObject) {
  this.mySharedObject = mySharedObject;
```

In addition to the lifecycle management this way allows easy unit testing of classes that use the shared object (like 'MyWebHandler' in this case) - now uou can create a stub/mock of the shared object and pass it into the handler - something that cannot really be easily done when using statics

So in summary if you can use spring and define it as a bean - by all means do so, the usage of statics is discouraged if you already have a dependency injection container

Comment: I tried @autowired as well as the Constructor Injection. I did not check for threadsafe but autowired is a bit more comfortable because of no constructors needed. Is autowired as good as the constructor injection or is there a flaw?

Comment: Thread safety has nothing to do with spring, but the same is true for static object (if it has an internal state - many threads can update it simultaneously). Its up to the human engineer to resolve thread safety issues. As for Autowired vs Constructor injection - its subjective, I prefer constructor injection, since it allows easy unit testing (how do you initialize dependency which is autowired without ugly reflection)?  If you're concerned about the need to write a constructor you can use Lombok, it has "AllArgsConstructor" and given a single constructor - spring injects everything correcly

Answer (score 1):

If you have shared object  first of all it should not contain any state as differents components can change it and also it should be thread safe.
It is fine to reuse it across all components via @Autowired annotation but you need to be sure that it is threadsafe. Spring bean scope singleton is not thread safe out of box it dependes how you write the code.

You can use as static method but it dependes on logic which you  have and if those component has an dependency on another objects and if they need to in spring IOC.